# Parsing flash cookies (.SOL files) with PHP

Tags: php, flash

Is there a PHP library/class which provides parsing capabilities for Flash cookie files (.SOL) by any chance?  I'm trying to avoid writing one myself :)

Regards,

Mark

Comment: What is your scenario? I can't think of a situation where this would make sense, seeing as PHP is running on server side and [SOLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Shared_Object) are stored on client side? But I can be wrong, of course.

Comment: Hi Pekka. Our webapp sets SOLs and as part of our automated test suite, we'd like to start checking that they are set correctly. Our automated tests are built in php.

Answer (score -2):

Flash cookies are just normal cookies ... you should be able to access using $_COOKIE['cookiename'];